# Error: onFailure:com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 57213780054

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2, android-api-levels

Cannot get the Response from the Retrofit showing the JsonSyntaxException. I am getting the perfect response in Logcat by HTTPLoggingInterceptor but unable to get the resonse on onSuccess() method in call.enque().

Here is my api.

```
 {
"collection_listings": [
    {
        "collection_id": 57213780054,
        "updated_at": "2018-04-30T02:12:55-04:00",
        "body_html": "",
        "default_product_image": null,
        "handle": "men",
        "image": {
            "created_at": "2018-04-30T01:11:11-04:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2331/3377/collections/men.jpg?v=1525065071"
        },
        "title": "Men",
        "sort_order": "best-selling",
        "published_at": "2018-04-30T01:10:24-04:00"
    },
    {
        "collection_id": 57213911126,
        "updated_at": "2018-04-30T01:56:41-04:00",
        "body_html": "",
        "default_product_image": null,
        "handle": "kids",
        "image": {
            "created_at": "2018-04-30T01:57:03-04:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2331/3377/collections/kid.jpg?v=1525067823"
        },
        "title": "Kids",
        "sort_order": "best-selling",
        "published_at": "2018-04-30T01:56:41-04:00"
    },
    {
        "collection_id": 57213878358,
        "updated_at": "2018-04-30T01:52:36-04:00",
        "body_html": "",
        "default_product_image": null,
        "handle": "women",
        "image": {
            "created_at": "2018-04-30T01:53:01-04:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2331/3377/collections/women.jpg?v=1525067581"
        },
        "title": "Women",
        "sort_order": "best-selling",
        "published_at": "2018-04-30T01:52:36-04:00"
    },
    {
        "collection_id": 57206145110,
        "updated_at": "2018-04-28T08:22:10-04:00",
        "body_html": "",
        "default_product_image": null,
        "handle": "test",
        "image": null,
        "title": "test",
        "sort_order": "best-selling",
        "published_at": "2018-04-28T08:22:10-04:00"
    },
    {
        "collection_id": 57205882966,
        "updated_at": "2018-04-28T07:56:28-04:00",
        "body_html": "",
        "default_product_image": null,
        "handle": "bath-rugs",
        "image": null,
        "title": "Bath rugs",
        "sort_order": "best-selling",
        "published_at": "2018-04-28T07:56:28-04:00"
    },
    {
        "collection_id": 57205850198,
        "updated_at": "2018-04-28T07:55:36-04:00",
        "body_html": "",
        "default_product_image": null,
        "handle": "bath-mats",
        "image": null,
        "title": "Bath mats",
        "sort_order": "best-selling",
        "published_at": "2018-04-28T07:55:36-04:00"
    },
    {
        "collection_id": 57127534678,
        "updated_at": "2018-04-28T05:51:00-04:00",
        "body_html": "<h3>DISCOVER THE CLASSICS</h3>\r\n<p><i>An enduring classic for every bath, we continue to elevate our solid collections by crafting each towel using innovative techniques and the finest organic, Egyptian and Turkish cottons and cotton blends.</i></p>",
        "default_product_image": null,
        "handle": "bath-towels",
        "image": {
            "created_at": "2018-04-16T08:44:13-04:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2331/3377/collections/2-1_Solid-Towels_112017c_1.jpg?v=1523882653"
        },
        "title": "bath towels",
        "sort_order": "best-selling",
        "published_at": "2018-04-28T05:51:00-04:00"
    },
    {
        "collection_id": 57127501910,
        "updated_at": "2018-04-28T05:51:00-04:00",
        "body_html": "<h3>STEP INTO COMFORT</h3>\r\n<p><i>Step into indulgence with our exquisite selection of bath rugs and bath mats. Expertly designed, each collection captures style ranging from the distinctly textured to the ultra-absorbent and supremely plush.</i></p>",
        "default_product_image": null,
        "handle": "bath-mats-and-bath-rugs",
        "image": {
            "created_at": "2018-04-16T08:41:52-04:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2331/3377/collections/bath-rugs_4.jpg?v=1523882512"
        },
        "title": "bath-mats and bath-rugs",
        "sort_order": "best-selling",
        "published_at": "2018-04-28T05:51:00-04:00"
    },
    {
        "collection_id": 57127436374,
        "updated_at": "2018-04-28T05:51:00-04:00",
        "body_html": "",
        "default_product_image": null,
        "handle": "bath-accessories",
        "image": {
            "created_at": "2018-04-16T08:36:15-04:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2331/3377/collections/7_Accessories_112017c.jpg?v=1523882175"
        },
        "title": "BATH ACCESSORIES",
        "sort_order": "best-selling",
        "published_at": "2018-04-28T05:51:00-04:00"
    },
    {
        "collection_id": 57127403606,
        "updated_at": "2018-04-28T05:50:59-04:00",
        "body_html": "",
        "default_product_image": null,
        "handle": "bath-robes",
        "image": {
            "created_at": "2018-04-16T08:34:39-04:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2331/3377/collections/4_bathrobes_112017c_1.jpg?v=1523882079"
        },
        "title": "bath robes",
        "sort_order": "best-selling",
        "published_at": "2018-04-28T05:50:59-04:00"
    },
    {
        "collection_id": 57127338070,
        "updated_at": "2018-04-28T05:50:59-04:00",
        "body_html": "",
        "default_product_image": null,
        "handle": "all",
        "image": {
            "created_at": "2018-04-16T08:37:10-04:00",
            "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2331/3377/collections/new-arrivals-042018.jpg?v=1523882230"
        },
        "title": "all products",
        "sort_order": "best-selling",
        "published_at": "2018-04-28T05:50:59-04:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

**APIClient.java**

```
 public class APIClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
private static final String BASE_URL = "https://ps-test.myshopify.com/admin/";

public static Retrofit getClient() {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    return retrofit;
  }
}
```

**ApiInterface.java**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("collection_listings.json")
    Call<Example> getCollectionList(@Header("Authorization") String accessToken);
}
```

Implementation in Activity:

```
private void fillListCategories() {

    apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<Example> call = apiInterface.getCollectionList("Basic OWUzNmY1NWVlNGY1NTk0YWE4OTFkZjg4MTAyYzBhMjg6MWQ3MmM0YmIwMzBiZmNlOTM5OWRlYmM4NjM3ZWFlYjM=");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("Collection List", "onResponse:" + response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Issue", "onFailure:" + t.fillInStackTrace());
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `long` type for `collection_id`  in your `Example` model class .

Comment: @ADM I have List of CollectionListing in my model class. Like this:  
    private List<CollectionListing> collectionListings = null;

    public List<CollectionListing> getCollectionListings() {
        return collectionListings;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get collection_id as long var or string in your Example class. because you are getting collection_id as a int but it's out of int range.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: FYI `int` is 32Bits in java thats makes it `-2,147,483,648 - 2,147,483,647`. What you are indicating is `short`  which is 16 Bits.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `float` or `double` or `String` instead of an `int`, in your model.

Answer (score 0):

Take all variable as string.

```
var or val xxxName: String = ""
```